# How to load an external JavaScript on a condition

Tags: javascript, html, asynchronous, browser, pagespeed

The question is how to rewrite a static HTML script embedding:

```
<script async id="__script__id__"
              type="text/javascript"
              src="//abc.xyz.com/js/script.js">
</script>
```

into a programmatic embedding which allows loading the script only on a certain condition.

The **bounty** is set for a description of how static/programmatic embedding differ from one another, specifically:

1. Explain how JS specification treats programmatically added scripts — when they are loaded and executed — with authoritative references.
2. Explain how converting script embedding from HTML inline to programmatic affects browser optimizations (it's known that browser scans for HTML script tags with `src` attribute and preloads them) with authoritative references.

Comment: If you know with 100% certainty that this script is only used on desktop, it must have some way of detecting that. Use the same criteria to load the script.

Comment: @Ouroborus Detecting is easy. The question is how to rewrite a static HTML-code into JavaScript which decides whether to load the script and loads it programmatically.

Comment: @DenisKulagin, what you _basically_ should do is write a new `<script>` tag from javascript, using the DOM.

Comment: Do you really want this though? I often resize my desktop browser, even to mobile-layouts at time.

Comment: @Evert It's a trade-off to save mobile users some cellular traffic and some battery.

Comment: Updated the OP to make it more generic and to be a better contribution to the community shared knowledge.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

If you've already figured out how to detect your criteria then loading another script goes like this:

```html
<head>
<!-- the usual head stuff goes here -->
<script>
// replace `criteria` with your actual criteria
if(criteria) {
  const script = document.createElement('script');
  script.id = '__script__id__';
  script.type = 'text/javascript';
  script.async = true;
  script.src = '//abc.xyz.com/js/script.js';
  document.head.append(script);
}
</script>
<!-- remaining scripts go here -->
<!-- injected script will end up here -->
</head>
```

Check for the criteria, create the element, set its properties, add it to the document.

---

I took a shot at finding details on this mechanism. The best I could find was from MDN on the topic of script element [`async` and `defer` properties](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLScriptElement#properties):

> The exact processing details for these attributes are complex, involving many different aspects of HTML, and therefore are scattered throughout the specification. [These algorithms](https://www.w3.org/html/wg/drafts/html/master/scripting-1.html#prepare-a-script) describe the core ideas, but they rely on the parsing rules for `<script>` [start](https://www.w3.org/html/wg/drafts/html/master/syntax.html#scriptTag) and [end](https://www.w3.org/html/wg/drafts/html/master/syntax.html#scriptEndTag) tags in HTML, [in foreign content](https://www.w3.org/html/wg/drafts/html/master/syntax.html#scriptForeignEndTag), and [in XML](https://www.w3.org/html/wg/drafts/html/master/the-xhtml-syntax.html#scriptTagXML); the rules for the [`document.write()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/write) method; the handling of [scripting](https://www.w3.org/html/wg/drafts/html/master/webappapis.html#scripting); and so on.

Unfortunately, I do not have the necessary familiarity with W3's various HTML specs to turn it into plain English and it looks like it would take quite a bit of time to become that familiar.

Comment: Thanks. But how to make sure the loader script is executed right away and the conditioned script is put into async loading queue as if it's loaded via HTML code (as in the OP). If it's guaranteed by the JS engine, could you point that out explicitly, please.

Comment: You don't actually have to set async as I did here. (You also don't generally need to set type either, unless the server is misconfigured.) Dynamically added script are [async by default](https://javascript.info/script-async-defer#dynamic-scripts). As for having it execute right away, ensure the script is inlined (not loaded from a url) and that it appears as the first script in the head.

Comment: Tested it out and it works like a charm.